# Xen guest VM with two static IP address

Tags: ip, xen, bridge

I have installed Xen4Centos on Centos7, having single NIC with bridge network and have two VMs on that.

In one VM, I want to add two static IP one for webserver and one for mail server.

So I have created IP alias in guest VM, it was created but it was not pinging from outside public network or from the host.

So if you have any idea how to add second IP in the guest VM then please let me know.

I have searched on Google but most of the tutorials had given example for one IP only.

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out the way to listen the second IP from public network.

I have added second interface in the VM configuration file with MAC address, so inside VM it looks like eth0 and eth1.

Then I have created a routing table for eth1 and added default gateway to eth1. [ **ip route add default via XXX.XX.XXX.112 dev eth1 table eth1**].

So doing this way second IP in VM was reachable from public network.